# Could not determine join condition with many-to-many join Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting the following error in SQLAlchemy:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on
>   relationship Membership.user - there are no foreign keys linking these
>   tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a
>   ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin'
>   expression.

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between the User and Event tables.  The objective is to have User be added as "Members" of an Event.  The event is also "Owned" by one user but this is a different one-to-many relationship.

```
class Membership(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event_membership'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), primary_key=True),
    time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable = False, default = func.now())

    user = db.relationship("Event",back_populates="memberships",foreign_keys=[])
    event = db.relationship("User",back_populates="members")


class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key =True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), index = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), index = True)
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    questions = db.relationship('Question',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')
    events = db.relationship('Event',backref='owner',lazy='dynamic')
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=False)
    #moderating_events = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('event.id'))
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=False)
    lastseen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    validated = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=False)

    memberships = db.relationship("Membership", back_populates= "user" )

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(),primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    event_code = db.Column(db.String(30))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    #owner = db.relationship("User",back_populates="events")
    questions = db.relationship('Question',backref='event',lazy='dynamic')
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    active_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    meeting_time = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    #moderators = db.relationship('User', backref='event_moderator',lazy='dynamic')
    moderate_questions = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=True)
    allow_anonymous = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False,default=True)

    members = db.relationship("Membership", back_populates="event")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not new to me! I face it 2 month ago and I resolve it in this way for many to many relationship 
you will have to edit your association table "Membership".
then you can pass it as secondary argument of relationship in user

try this code:

```
Membership =db.Table(
'Membership',
db.Column('User_id',db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('User.id')),
db.Column('Event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Event.id')),
```

and in User Table table add:

```
 Events = relationship("Event",
                secondary=Membership)
```

find more [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#) in the official documentation of SqlALchemy

Comment: This works but I need to be able to add a field to the relationship table.  Making it an Association Object not just table.

Comment: You can add a field in the association table like you do in your previous table... for example a date it will works good

Comment: Or you can add backref argument in the relationship property to be able to use it as an object